# Django paginator and zipping

Tags: django, web-development-server, paginator

I want to iterate a list and query set in my html render, but am unable to get the Django paginator to work. I zipped the list and queryset so I could iterate them together.
[Here's my views.py code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqKsF.png)

Oddly enough, I am able to access the data in both lists with {% for item1, item2 in posts %}, but {{ posts.next_page_number }} is just blank. How can I access the page in the templating engine?

Comment: Also, you should post your code in the question not as an image. Use the back tick ` symbol x3 to open a code block and another 3 back ticks to close it. This helps others who might have the same issue find this more easily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `item2` is the `Page` object as you zipped it second. So presumably you would do it as follows…

```
{{ item2.next_page_number }}
```